# Can you move unlicensed accounts around using PowerShell in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, sharepoint-online-powershell

I'm trying to bulk move users from one group to another in a SharePoint online group. I ran this script:

[image]

And it moved only users that have O365 licenses. When it tried to move the other users, I got this error:

[image]

Am I only able to move users that have licensed accounts? Or is there something that I'm missing in the script? For what it's worth, I'm working inside of a GCC High tenant.

Any insight would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user doesn't have an Exchange Online license, they won't have an Email address. This means that $User.Email will be blank. Try using $User.LoginName instead of $User.Email.

This would also mean you don't have to prepend  `i:0#.f|membership|` to email to get $UserID. You can simply use `Add-PnpGroupMember -LoginName $User.LoginName -Identity $DestinationGroupName`

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much. I'll definitely remember that going forward when using other scripts.